# paging in jsp while using ajax

Tags: jsp, jquery

I have a jsp page where i have placed a dropdown,after selecting any client i am populating details related to that client which is in tabular form.
i am getting multiple rows through ajax on that page, now i want to place next and forward buttons to add paging to show 10 rows per page for e.g if i am getting 20 rows then it should come in two page instead of coming all 20 rows . How to do this stuff ? Any one having any sample code to share ? any idea to share ?
P.S. : i am using sybase as a database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still want to retrieve the full set of data from the service and add the pagination in the browser?

Then you can use a JQuery plugin: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination